# Make and take set identification - white, tan, brown, and a long yellow axle

Tags: set-identification

My kids got these pieces in a plain clear bag for Christmas 2021. I think it is part of a LEGO Make-and-Take event at a Toys R Us from this past year or something but they didn’t get any instructions. Is anyone able to identify and get instructions for it?

[image: white, tan, brown, and a long yellow axle]

Comment: Whatever it is it's not inventoried on BrickLink: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=14769pb196&in=S

Answer (score 6):

I put together a model of this owl, using my best guess when there was ambiguity. It uses all the parts in the image, plus some extras (namely; the wings, beak, eyes, some slopes).
You can view the 3D model here: https://www.mecabricks.com/en/models/Abjp4W9Dj5y

[image]

---

Searching for Lego Make and Take, I found this Harry Potter Owl model that appears to be made of the parts from your bag, but you may be missing a few.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find building instructions for it, but they can definitely be inferred from the image.
[image]